# Search Specific Element In array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

I am trying to find a specific object from array of objects in mongodb.

I am trying this

```
Company.findOne ({
"configuration.macAddress": "AB-90-dF-8d"
});
```

It returns me the exact company but it returns all the configuration array 
I want only configuration with matching macAddress

Answer (score 1):

Instead use aggregate().  $unwind the configuration array first, then you can $match the specific element only.

```
Company.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$configuration"
    },
    {
        "$match":{
            "configuration.macAddress": "AB-90-dF-8d"
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $elemMatch to find a particular object in an array.

Company.find({ configuration: { $elemMatch: { macAddress: "AB-90-dF-8d"} } } );

can you show me your array of objects?